# Помогите исправить ошибку в коде pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Начал писать разные функции для сокращения кода, и вот на что наткнулся.
Написал такую функцию:

```
function sql($sql,$array)
{
global $db;
try
{
$start =  $db->prepare($sql);
$start -> $db->execute($array);
return $start->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
return false;
}
}
```

И запустил её:

```
$get = sql("SELECT `title`, `full` FROM `News` WHERE `id` = ? LIMIT 1" , array($_GET['n']));
exit($get['title']);
```

По идее же должно работать? Выдает ошибку:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDO could not be converted to string in /var/www/html/system/functions.php
```

Как исправить?

Answer (score 3):

Вам возвращает в $get ObjectPdo, а вы его пытаетесь вывести как строку на 54й строке. 
Для начала, нужно сделать так

```
$result = $get->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);//Или любой другой тип
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Я хотел просто узнать что выдает данная переменная через var_dump. Ваш вариант выдает ту-же ошибку.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: Обновил код в сообщении.

Comment: Там уже по идее должна выдаватся из функции переменная с массивом полученных данных.

Answer (score -1):

Допустил банальную ошибку :)
Рабочий код:

```
<?php
function sql($sql,$array)
{
$db_host = '';
$db_user = '';
$db_pass = '';
$db_base = '';
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.$db_base.';host='.$db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
try
{
$start =  $db->prepare($sql);
$start -> execute($array);
return $start->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
return false;
}
}
$get = sql("SELECT `title`, `full` FROM `News` WHERE `id` = ? LIMIT 1" , array(1));
print_r($get['title']);
?>
```

Comment: Если в конфиге прописано подключение, то можно просто global $db включать в функцию, чтобы каждый раз не писать (либо в классе это все сделать).

Comment: Я так и сделал, код поместил в одну функцию для наглядности, и для новичков.

Comment: новичкам такое показывать - это даже для похапешника перебор.